Can I use a variable to select an OptionButton in a UserForm based on a cell value?
I'm creating a report template with a UserForm to allow users to simply enter data. The data gets put into a hidden sheet so that users can't go in and delete information after entry. The information is displayed in a custom report on the first page of the file. All of that is working great. However, sometimes users make an error in data entry, and I want them to be able to select the row, press a button, and have a UserForm pop up with the fields pre-populated with the relevant information. They can then edit the incorrect information, press save, and merrily go about their day. All of that is fine, except that I have used OptionButtons 1 - 5 to set the priority, and I don't know how to set the correct OptionButton to 'True' based on the priority shown in the report.
I can set the defPri variable to, say, '5' for low priority, but how do I then set OptionButton5 to 'True' based on that value? I have tried Me.OptionButton & defPri = True, but obviously that does not work.
It might not be possible, but before I give up completely I thought I would ask here.
Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Me.Controls("OptionButton" & defPri) = True

Radiobutton may be a better choice for setting priority.

@TimWilliams That worked a treat, thank you so much. I can't upvote yet, but I just wanted to show my appreciation!

@AcsErno - Isn't a radio button the same thing as an option button? Or am I way off base there?
